# Windows installer error. "This installation package could not be opened..."

Tags: windows-installer

Im trying to run a .MSI file with some settings but i keep getting the error "This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

If i run the program manually (by clicking on the .MSI file) it works.
But i would like to run it with remote commands in a PSession.

This is the command i use, when i get the error:
"msiexec /qb /i OpenOTPCredentialProviderSetup.msi SERVER_URL=http://192.168.11.37:8080/openotp/ SOAP_TIMEOUT=10 "

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: I would either create a log file (`... /l*v verbose.log`) and look for errors, test with something else that can open MSI files, or check with Process Explorer or Process Monitor to see if the file is locked. (But I'm not sure how the PSession figures in.)

Comment: You should specify the actual full path to the MSI file.

Comment: What is a "PSession"?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Getting something similar

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the file, go to properties and click the button "Unblock" at the bottom of the window. Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

In Administrator PowerShell had this problem with this command:

```
msiexec .\mymsi.msi /qb /i
```

When I changed it to this command it worked:

```
msiexec d:\mymsi.msi /qb
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many solutions available, but I suggest starting with the easiest one: cutting and pasting the file into your C drive and then installing it from there.